# How do I add maps/navigation component to multiple activities?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am creating my first app learning as I go along and I've hit a wall.

My app consists of multiple activities and now I want to add a map component - if I may call it that, to each activity with predefined coordinates. How does one go about that? All I know is that am going to need a maps API.

Comment: Look up some google maps tutorials.  This question is way too broad.  COme back when you have a more specific issue.

Comment: You can use Google's Maps SDK for Android https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start